# Display image on textview without using httpConnection

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I want to allow user to upload file. For this purpose i am using firebase-storage. If the uploaded file is image i want to show it on the screen in the textView along with some texts.

```
    if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
        final Uri selectedFile = data.getData();

StorageReference uploadRef = storageRef.child("fileName");

        UploadTask uploadTask = uploadRef.putFile(selectedFile);

        uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            }
        }).addOnPausedListener(new OnPausedListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onPaused(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                System.out.println("Upload is paused");
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

               String xyz = String.valueOf(taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl());

            }
        });
```

In onSuccessListener i can get the url of uploaded file. how can i use it to show image on textView without using depricated httpConnection?

Comment: What do you mean show the image on `TextView`? That doesn't make any sense. You would need an `ImageView` for that.

Comment: you can add drawableLeft in textview programmatically